OneDrive Auto-Download Link
I utilize OneDrive personal do provide software upgraded files to my users. I program in .NET Framework and NET CORE.
Since last week the usage of "api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares" is reporting an authentication error on all of them. In fact, now my software cannot upgrade itself even if detecting a new version doe to the above restriction.
Does anyone know hot to convert the newest usual link (eg.: https://1drv.ms/u/c/) to the "api" format?  My converter does not converts a valid one anymore.
Thanks!

You are not giving us much to work with. No actual error message. No code how you create the share URL, etc

I saw that Microsoft had modificed the "public access" to OneDrive links. Now MS requires an OAuth 2.0 ID before access any file - even public ones.
